# Python: Imbalanced data for XGBoost Multi-label classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset of a stock's returns where the Y-label is price change direction (= 2 if upward tick, = 1 if downward tick, and = 0 if no move. Some of the features, X, include the lagged label values (i.e. the previous day's price direction change).

I am trying to run the XGBoost classification model, however my data is highly imbalanced. Most of the Y label values are = 0 meaning the stock price did not move.

How can I incorporate this imbalance in a multi-label XGBoost classification problem?

My code is the following:

```
X = df[["ret_D_lag_1", "ret_D_lag_2", "ret_D_lag_3"]]
y = df["ret_D_t1"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

# use DMatrix for xgboost
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)

# set xgboost params
param = {
    'max_depth': 3,  # the maximum depth of each tree
    'eta': 0.3,  # the training step for each iteration
    'silent': 1,  # logging mode - quiet
    'objective': 'multi:softprob',  # error evaluation for multiclass training
    'num_class': 3}  # the number of classes that exist in this datset
num_round = 20  # the number of training iterations

# Train the model
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)

# Predict and choose highest probability for each label
preds = bst.predict(dtest)
best_preds = np.asarray([np.argmax(line) for line in preds])
```